# How to create an email notification by clicking a button on a list?

Tags: 2013, list, email, form, person

I have created a form in a list, and one of the fields required is a person/group field that I would like to send a notification email to when the form is submitted. I have a button at the bottom of the form and would like to assign a rule on the button to generate an email. I am having trouble finding the correct field to enter into the "to" section of the email.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create SharePoint Designer workflow which would run after the new item has been created. In it you can use `Email` action and select the field which holds the person as the receiver of the email.

More on creating simple SharePoint designer workflows can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo).

Comment: Is there a way to create a workflow to send the notification when a certain button is clicked? Right now I have a "save & Submit" "approve" and "deny" button that I would need the email notification for. So just having it for when the item is created would not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet on button click :

```
function processSendEmail() {  

if ($("#empEmailId").val() != null) {  
    var userEmaiId = $("#empEmailId").val();  
}  
else {  

    alert("EmailId Should not be empty");  
}  



var From = '';  
var To = userEmaiId;  
var Body = 'You have been successfully submitted the data to List';  
var SubjectOfEmail = 'Email Notification Using REST API';  


sendEmailNotification(From, To, Body, SubjectOfEmail);
```

}

function sendEmailNotification(From, To, Body, SubjectOfEmail) {

```
hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));  

var constructedURL = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";  
$.ajax({  
    contentType: 'application/json',  
    url: constructedURL,  
    type: "POST",  
    data: JSON.stringify({  
        'properties': {  
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },  
            'From': From,  
            'To': { 'results': [To] },  
            'Body': Body,  
            'Subject': SubjectOfEmail  
        }  
    }  
  ),  
    headers: {  
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  
    },  
    success: function (data) {  
        alert('Email Sent Successfully');  


    },  
    error: function (err) {  
        alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));  


    }  
});
```

}